# XML-Export of EER Diagram from MySQL Workbench

Tags: xml, database-design, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

Is there a way to export a XML file of an EER Diagram from MySQL Workbench (used on macOS Sierra)? Unfortunately I'm only shown the beneath options. The predecessor of MySQL Workbench - DB Designer 4 - had this feature, but this program is no longer available.

[image: Screenshot from MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no option to export as xml. However the model itself is just xml. You can rename your mwb file to zip and extract it. Look in the resulting folder and you will see the xml.

Comment: @NiklasBuschner if my answer helped you then mark it as such (see the check mark below the voting buttons).

Comment: I just did it, sorry for forgetting it.